# SSIS - find element in table, use its key and insert to another table

Tags: ssis

I have database with following 3 tables:

[image]

- Customers.CustomerId is integer and PK
- Addresses.AddressId is integer and PK
- CustomerAddresses.Customer_CustomerId is integer and FK to Customers
- CustomerAddresses.Address_AddressId is integer and FK to Addresses
- Customers.EntityId is GUID
- Addresses.EntityId is GUID

I use SQL Server Integration Services.

I have also XML file with pairs of addressEntityID and customerEntityId. These are are EntityIDs (GUID), that need to be mapped to IDs (integer) and inserted into CustomerAddresses.

*How to map this relationship and import to CustomerAddresses?*

I want to do something like, for each row, `select CustomerId from Customers where EntityId = {0}` and then use this value to insert. Can this be done?

And before you suggest, that I should use EntityId as PK, the reason is, that those are not provided for all data in database. Only data, that are imported, and come from another system, those have EntityId.

Comment: Quick and dirty. Can you use the Lookup transformation to do this? Have you tried that?

Comment: The driver of the data is the XML file. Based on the two values in there, you need to find the corresponding Entity (Customers or Address) and then record that relationship in the `CustomerAddresses` table, yeah?

Comment: @rvphx, I could, but have no idea how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In Data Flow drop XML source
2. Add Derived column, map values from XML (it is necessary to map from string to GUID)
3. Add Lookup, connect to Addresses table, create JOIN from derived AddressGuid to EntityId. AddressId is output.

[image: Lookup configuration]

4. Add another Lookup and do the same for Customers table
5. Add DB destination, map values from Lookup to AddressId and CustomerId

Comment: That looks about right. Do you need the EntityID in the steps below the Lookup? If so, go ahead and check the "EntityID" tick box. But the solution looks great!